# Resources in Merged Dictionary not loaded on label

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have created Resource Dictionary for Dimens and Colors in project

root: MyProject.Resources.Values
/Dimens
/Colors

Colors:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    x:Class="MyProject.Resources.Values.Colors">
    <!-- Colours Light Theme -->
   
    <Color x:Key="BlackColor">#000000</Color>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Dimens:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    x:Class="MyProject.Resources.Values.Dimens">

    <x:Double x:Key="FontSize18">18</x:Double>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Added them in App class as:

```
<unity:PrismApplication  xmlns:unity="clr-namespace:Prism.Unity;assembly=Prism.Unity.Forms"
                         xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                         xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:MyProject.Resources.Values"
                         x:Class="MyProject.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <resources:Dimens />
                <resources:Colors />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</unity:PrismApplication>
```

And tried to use them on page:

```
<Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                   FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize18}"
                   TextColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

But nothing is loaded on the label.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `x:Class` attribute from the root tag of the `ResourceDictionary` files.

Colors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                >
     <!-- Colours Light Theme -->

     <Color x:Key="BlackColor">#000000</Color>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Dimens:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                >

    <x:Double x:Key="FontSize18">18</x:Double>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

then in you app.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Colors.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dimens.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I made the solution like this at the very first beginning with a small difference in the source Source="Resources/Values/Colors.xaml" cuz it was in my subfolder but I get the same outcome

Comment: @Stefanija You should use  \  instead of  /.,like the update above.

Comment: Would that work for mac/ios, isn't that windows path convention? Will give it a try @Leo Zhu

Comment: I tried that but it also not working. I doubt there is some issue with app.xaml being prism

Comment: @Stefanija i run it on Android device,and it works well,i will test it on ios then tell you the result.

Comment: @Stefanija It alos works on ios,did you set the xaml  to `BuildAction : Embedded resource` ?

Comment: Hey, I made a bad mistake on App class I've put InitializeComponent() on the constructor instead in InitializeComponent() class. After that change it works, with no change as above. Your solution works as well. Just was not the case in my scenario... Anyway, I'll upvote it since it is working solution:) And for "\" I thinkl we should stick on "/" cuz "\" is windows convention and path may not be recognized in some cases :) Thanks!

Comment: @Stefanija If you don't remove the `x:Class` attribute from the root tag of the `ResourceDictionary` files,could it work ?